# function fails to use local variable when it is called inside a Module

Tags: scoping, list-manipulation

I have these two functions `fun` and `microstep`.Fun makes use of a Module construct within which I define the  `Array` I need to store the values of magnetization for different temperatures (each case stored in a different row).
 `microstep` is the function that store the data at the correct position at each step of the Monte Carlo algorithm. The monte Carlo procedure doesn't matter really much now, what bothers me is that when  I define the magnetization array inside fun, the function doesn't work properly:

```
   fun [numbofsets_, nsteps_] := Module [{confinit, magnetization, index},

  index = 
   MapIndexed[   { #2[[1]], #   } &, numbofsets   ];     (* {index,
  temp} tuple*) 
  confinit = RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, {10, 10}];             (*  
  initial random matrix *)
  magnetization = 
   ConstantArray[ 0, {Length@numbofsets, nsteps}];


  Table[   

   NestList[
     microstep[ ##[[1]], ##[[2]], ##[[3]], ##[[4]]       ]         &  \
  , {   index[[i, 1]], index[[i, 2]]   ,   confinit, 2  }          ,
      nsteps];

   , {i, 1, Length@numbofsets}];

  ]
```

and

```
microstep[tindex_, temp_, matrix_, mcindex_] :=
 Module[{ tempmatrix = matrix, dimx, dimy, x , y , it = 1/temp, down, 
   up, left, right, spinsum , randnum, bool = False    , J = 1       },

  (* generic Metropolis Alghoritm *)
  dimx = Dimensions[matrix][[1]];
  dimy = Dimensions[matrix][[2]];
  x = RandomInteger[{1, dimx}];
  y = RandomInteger[{1, dimy}];
  randnum = RandomReal[];
  spinsum = 
   Plus[Compile`GetElement[matrix, Mod[x + 1, dimx, 1], y], 
    Compile`GetElement[matrix, Mod[x - 1, dimx, 1], y], 
    Compile`GetElement[matrix, x, Mod[y - 1, dimy, 1]], 
    Compile`GetElement[matrix, x, Mod[y + 1, dimy, 1]]];

  If[2*J *spinsum*tempmatrix[[x, y]] < 0 \[Or] 
    randnum < E^(- it*2*J*tempmatrix[[x, y]]*spinsum)
   ,
   tempmatrix[[x, y]] = -Compile`GetElement[matrix, x, y]; bool = True
   ];
  (*  tricky part  starts here *)

  If[bool,
   magnetization[[tindex, mcindex]] = 
     Abs[(magnetization[[tindex, mcindex - 1]] + 
        2 *tempmatrix[[x, y]])] ;                                      
   , 
   magnetization[[tindex, mcindex]] = 
     magnetization[[tindex, mcindex - 1]];

   ];
  {tindex, temp, tempmatrix, mcindex + 1}

  ]
```

now if i run

```
fun [{2, 3, 4}, 10]
```

i get

> "Part specification magnetization[[1,1]] is longer than depth of \
>   object"

Meanwhile If I declare the magnetization array outside the Module, the function works properly giving me the   correctly stored   values, but it forces me to use global variables :

```
magnetization = ConstantArray[0, {3, 11}];
fun [{2, 3, 4}, 10];
magnetization
```

> {   {0, 2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 6, 8, 6, 6},   {0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2,
>   0, 2},   {0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 8, 6, 6, 4, 4}  })

I think the problem rise up from the fact that module is a scoping construct but I  thought that a function called inside it would see the local variable but it doesn't and I don't know how to solve the problem. In c-like languages pointers can be used, is there anything similar in mathematica? 
Also, as always, any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Have you tried reducing the example so the answer could be more generic and to get more attention?

Comment: i guess i can simplify the step function a little bit.

Comment: This is one of the cases where you would need the "dynamical scoping" of `Block` instead of the "lexical scoping" of `Module`. If you replace `Module` by `Block` in your definition of `fun`, everything should work fine.

Comment: @mmeent uhm I will try it as soon as I reach home

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work out for you?

Here I added `magnetization` as additional argument and gave `microstep` the attibute `HoldAll` to allow for call by reference.

```
SetAttributes[microstep, HoldAll];
microstep[tindex_, temp_, matrix_, mcindex_, magnetization_] := 
 Module[{tempmatrix = matrix, dimx, dimy, x, y, it = 1/temp, down, up,
    left, right, spinsum, randnum, bool = False, 
   J = 1},(*generic Metropolis Alghoritm*)

  dimx = Dimensions[matrix][[1]];
  dimy = Dimensions[matrix][[2]];
  x = RandomInteger[{1, dimx}];
  y = RandomInteger[{1, dimy}];
  randnum = RandomReal[];
  spinsum = Plus[
    Compile`GetElement[matrix, Mod[x + 1, dimx, 1], y],
    Compile`GetElement[matrix, Mod[x - 1, dimx, 1], y],
    Compile`GetElement[matrix, x, Mod[y - 1, dimy, 1]],
    Compile`GetElement[matrix, x, Mod[y + 1, dimy, 1]]
    ];
  If[2*J*spinsum*tempmatrix[[x, y]] < 0 ∨ 
    randnum < E^(-it*2*J*tempmatrix[[x, y]]*spinsum), 
   tempmatrix[[x, y]] = -Compile`GetElement[matrix, x, y]; 
   bool = True];
  (*tricky part starts here*)
  If[bool, magnetization[[tindex, mcindex]] = Abs[(magnetization[[tindex, mcindex - 1]] + 2*tempmatrix[[x, y]])];, 
   magnetization[[tindex, mcindex]] = magnetization[[tindex, mcindex - 1]];
   ];
  {tindex, temp, tempmatrix, mcindex + 1}]
```

There was also a second issue within `fun`: Apparently, the array `magnetization` was set up a bit too short, so I prolonged it by `1`. Removing also some `;`, the function `fun` executes without error and returns a result. Checking wether the result is correct is up to you.

```
fun[numbofsets_, nsteps_] := 
 Module[{confinit, index}, 
  index = MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &, numbofsets];(*{index,temp} tuple*)

  confinit = RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, {10, 10}];(*initial random matrix*)

  magnetization = ConstantArray[0, {Length@numbofsets, nsteps + 1}];
  Table[
   NestList[
    microstep[##[[1]], ##[[2]], ##[[3]], ##[[4]], magnetization] &,
    {index[[i, 1]], index[[i, 2]], confinit, 2}, nsteps
    ]
   ,
   {i, 1, Length@numbofsets}]
  ]
```

Comment: I will let you know soon Henrik, the windows spring update hit my notebook with the strength of ten thousand suns :-(

Comment: Whoa... Good luck, then!

Comment: Though I still have to analyze the data, the array is properly filled. Thanks again henrik

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Just give your function `microstep[tindex_, temp_, matrix_, mcindex_]` an extra arg, so make it `microstep[tindex_, temp_, matrix_, mcindex_, magnetization_]` and feed it in as an argument.

By default `microstep` is looking for `magnetization` in the global scope, so you need to either make `magnetization` Global or make feed it in as an argument.

Additionally, if you want to rewrite values (e.g pass by reference instead of pass by value, which is what the above would do) you can pass in arguments in their `Held` form.

So your downvalue would now be `microstep[tindex_, temp_, matrix_, mcindex_, Hold[magnetization_]]`, and obviously change `fun` to call `microstep` with the extra argument.

If this is not clear, I can update with more code examples when I get to my machine that has Mma on it.

Cheers!

Edit -- It seems that if you look @Heinriks answer, he implemented what I was thinking.

Comment: i tried with hold and reporting the magnetization as argument, fun keeps giving  me back an empty array. the error is ` set {{},....} in the part assignment is not a symbol`. Btw i had completely forgotten about Hold, damn  few months of not using mathematica and i have already forgot many useful functions